os.path does not work with a /dev/ttyUSB0
I have a simple script to check if a USB device (UART) is plugged in.
(OS = Ubuntu 22.04, Python 3.10).
import os
path = os.path.join('dev', 'ttyUSB0')
print(f'DBG exists: {os.path.exists(path)}')
print(f'DBG isfile: {os.path.isfile(path)}')
print(f'DBG isdir : {os.path.isdir(path)}')
# print(f'DBG isdevdrive: {os.path.isdevdrive(path)}')
#  causes: AttributeError: module 'posixpath' has no attribute 'isjunction'
print(f'DBG islink: {os.path.islink(path)}')
# print(f'DBG isjunction: {os.path.isjunction(path)}')
#  causes: ditto
print(f'DBG lexists: {os.path.lexists(path)}')

output is:
DBG exists: False
DBG isfile: False
DBG isdir : False
DBG islink: False
DBG lexists: False

but the file definitely exists:
$ ls -al /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw----+ 1 root dialout 188, 0 Sep 25 10:42 /dev/ttyUSB0

Just curious, what is it about ttyUSB0 that makes the os.path.xx functions always report False?

isfile() only returns True for regular files, not device special files.

The code you posted doesn't show any assignment to path, so we have no idea what file you're actually testing for existence.  The string might have a trailing space or newline, for example.

Are you running the code as a user that has permission to see the contents of /dev ?  What are the permissions on /dev itself?

@jasonharper  thanks, updated the code above. I used os.path.join()

@JohnGordon  normal user permissions in Ubuntu, nothing special. No sudo in use. The permisions for /dev are:
drwxr-xr-x  23 root    root     5960 Sep 25 11:14 dev/

path = os.path.join('dev', 'ttyUSB0') This is the problem.  There is not a leading  slash on dev, therefore it assumes dev is a folder in the current directory.

@jasonharper That was it! Updated to path = os.path.join(os.sep, 'dev', 'ttyUSB0') and os.path.exists() returns True. Thanks! Post an answer and I will upvote it.

@JohnGordon  Yup figured that out as well. Thanks!

You should really use udev rules for that, your script is racy and quite unreliable in this sense.
